# Consequences of tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora being unavailable

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Our database servers are configured with the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files centrally located on a shared network drive. In every ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory we have a symbolic link pointing to the centrally-located tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files.  I want to understand the consequences of these files becoming unavailable in the case of a loss of connectivity to the network share.

1. Are these files used by any database processes, or only by client programs like SQL*Plus?
2. If these files became unavailable, would existing client connections be affected, or only new connections?
3. Would database links using the TNS aliases be broken while the tnsnames.ora file is unavailable?

Comment: From my own experience: 1. Yes they are accessed (I use SQL). 2. Existing connections will fail and new. 3. Database links will be broken.

Comment: point 2 above: new connections will fail, NOT existing

Comment: Some parameters in `sqlnet.ora` file have default values, check them from [Parameters for the sqlnet.ora File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006)

Comment: I'd reconsider doing this if I were you, and use Oracle Names Server instead. Allows for centralised management of TNS

Comment: @JSapkota gave a very thorough answer, but it boils down to this:  tnsnames.ora is, in effect, a telephone directory for _client_ processes.  But keep in mind, the database itself is acting as a client when it acesses a db_link.  Also, just  like a telephone directory, it is used _only_ when looking up a number to call.  It does not need to be kept in hand and open while talking on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

> Are these files used by any database processes, or only by client programs like SQL*Plus?

Yes, these files are used by Oracle processes while connecting to the database, once the connection is established they don't need these files.

For example,

If you have specified the following parameter in `sqlnet.ora` file on server side.

```
tcp.validnode_checking = yes
tcp.invited_nodes =<list the valid nodes here>
```

The Oracle server process will check whether the incoming connection request is valid or not. Once it finds the node is valid it will proceed ahead and it no longer needs the `sqlnet.ora` file.

Similarly, Oracle client process will look up TNS Name on `tnsnames.ora` file for the connection string. Once it finds the connection details to make connection it also no longer needs the `tnsnames.ora` file.

> If these files became unavailable, would existing client connections be affected, or only new connections?

Only the new connection will be impacted because existing connections have already used these files during the connection initiation.

> Would database links using the TNS aliases be broken while the `tnsnames.ora` file is unavailable?

If you are middle of the transaction using that database link and the `tnsnames.ora` is missing then it will not impact the on going transaction. However, next session which uses the TNS Name in database link will fail.

`ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`